# Click event firing anywhere on the document,

Tags: jquery, livequery

The code :

```
 $(".postAnswer").livequery("click", function (event) {


    appendControl($(this));
    event.preventDefault();


});
```

This code block is inside the document.ready function. What I am trying to do here is , on every click of the ".postAnswer" button , an ajax called is made and it returns html whic is then appended to the parent. The returned html contains the same link button with class of ".postAnswer" and I am using livequery to bind the events for the newly append controls.

In the above code, the click event is firing on a click anywhere on the document. Need some help resolving this issue.

Thanks

**EDIT**

PROBLEM SOLVED ...

Comment: Is appendControl is your own defined function?

Comment: yes, it is . The element which registers the click gets passed to the appendControl function and I am using that to identify the parent of the clicked button.

Comment: can you post more code or share js fiddle link ,it would help solve the problem?

Comment: why `livequery` and not `live`??

Comment: live or livequery both are ok , if it solves the problem.
@kvc . I have edit the question. can u check again . thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").live("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    if (id == "Like") likeAnswer(this);

    else if (id == "insertPost") appendControl(this);


});
```

this was how i changed it back. works fine now.